# Binding in code to property with operation without special ValueConverter

Tags: mvvmcross

In axml I can Bind like this

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility Status==0, Converter=Visibility"
```

but when I'm trying to do it in code:

```
set.Bind(_imgStatus).For(c => c.Hidden).To(vm => vm.Status == 0).WithConversion("Visibility");
```

or

```
set.Bind(_imgStatus).For(c => c.Hidden).To(vm => vm.Status.Equals(0)).WithConversion("Visibility");
```

I get error 
Property expression must be of the form 'x => x.SomeProperty.SomeOtherProperty' or 'x => x.SomeCollection[0].Property' (System.ArgumentException)

I'm aware that I can write my own ValueConverter, but I'm interested if there's a way to surpass that, since there's obviously a way to write it in axml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross doesn't include expressions like `To(vm => vm.Status == 0)` in the fluent syntax. This is partly because they are hard to code... and partly because their coding often requires runtime compilation (which iOS won't allow)

The only way around this is to use the `string` format in iOS - e.g. like in https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-35-Tibet/BindMe.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L63

So your sample might become something like:

```
 set.Bind(_imgStatus).For(c => c.Hidden).To("Visibility(Status == 0)");
```

or even (in this case):

```
 set.Bind(_imgStatus).For(c => c.Hidden).To("Status != 0");
```

There are also some `described` fluent methods to allow you to pass in the entire binding string - e.g. something like:

```
 set.Bind(_imgStatus).FullyDescribed("Hidden Visibility(Status != 0)");
```